# Can I pass a constructor to a function?

Tags: c++

I want to instantiate a base class pointer to point to a newly constructed derived class object. The actual class for the object will change depending on the application type, so I want to use a Factory method to switch on certain variables in order to construct the right object.

However I don't want to have to do the switch each time. In fact, once the application starts, the type of object I want to create in this situation will always be the same - so actually I only need to do this switch only once.

Can I pass in a derived class Constructor to the function creating the object?

For example:

```
typedef DerivedObject (*DerivedClassConstructor)( void );
class ContainingClass:
{
public:
    ContainingClass ( DerivedClassConstructor * f ) 
    {
       baseptr = f();
    }

    BaseClass * baseptr
};
```

Is there a better design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's pretty sane. Just pass a function object and save it since it seems you need to recall it later (otherwise why not pass the pointer directly and create the object before?)

```
class ContainingClass:
{
public:
    typedef boost::function<BaseClass*()> factory_fn;

public:
    ContainingClass (factory_fn f ) 
      :m_f(f)
    {
       baseptr = m_f();
    }

    BaseClass * baseptr
    factory_fn m_f;
};


template<typename T>
struct DerivedFactory {
    BaseClass *operator()() {
        return new T;
    }
};


ContainingClass c((DerivedFactory<DerivedClass>()));
```

Comment: can you think of any benefits of using a templatised function over templatising the ContainingClass as @Martin York has done? They seem semantically equivalent to me, but I might have missed something.

Comment: @BeeBand oh it depends. If you template it, any function that takes a `ContainingClass` needs to be a template too. Also, if you template it, this usage is not possible anymore: `ContainingClass getContaining() { if(foo) return DerivedFactory<A>(); else return DerivedFactory<B>(); }`. In other words, you won't be able to decide at runtime what factory implementation you use anymore

Answer (score 2):

Would it not be easier to templatise the code.
That way it looks like normal code.

```
class BaseClass
{};
class Derived: public BaseClass
{};

template<typename T>
class ContainingClass
{
    public:
        ContainingClass()
        {
            baseptr = new T();
        }

        BaseClass * baseptr;
};

int main()
{
     ContainingClass<Derived>  cont;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with a constructor, since a constructor is not actually returning a class instance.

You talk about a factory method, and you got half way towards actually using one. However, it is not a good idea to create a dependency from base class to derived class - why can't your factory method simply return (a pointer to) `BaseClass` objects?

```
typedef BaseClass* (*BaseClassFactory)( void );
```